# Export whole page of custom functions to main.js

Tags: javascript, function, import, export

I am attempting to export my `functions.js` into my `main.js` and for some reason i can't figure out how to do it. i can export each individual function with no problem but thats a lot of imports in my `main.js`. is there anyway i can export the whole page of functions and import them to the right file. I've searched up export on MDN but i couldn't find anything about exporting the whole page.

Comment: and you what have you tried doing?

Comment: If each function is exported in `functions.js` you can import them in bulk like `import * as allFuncs from '[path]/functions.js'`. Then access each function like `allFuncs.foo()`